# What is the difference between sorry and afraid? Are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Can anyone help me with the difference between "I'm sorry" and "I'm afraid"?

In the four following sentences, should I use "sorry", "afraid" or can I use both? And why?

1. I’m ________________ , I’m _________________ I can’t speak Spanish very well.
2. I’m ________________  , can you say that again please?
3. I’m ________________   his line is busy.
4. I’m ________________ but he’s in a meeting at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Your usage of the phrase

> I'm sorry *(but)*

is a formal, polite way of apologizing for *something* which can not be fulfilled, whereas using

> I'm afraid *(that)*

is used by BrE speakers to mean

> I *fear* you will be disappointed...

when your request can not be fulfilled.  Both mean you will not get what you want.

> 1. I’m **sorry** , I’m **afraid** I can’t speak Spanish very well.
> 2. I’m **sorry**, can you say that again please?
> 3. I’m **sorry/afraid** his line is busy.
>
> 4.a I’m **sorry** but he’s in a meeting at the moment.
>   4.b I’m **afraid** he’s in a meeting at the moment.

The difference may become more apparent in

> I'm sorry your [parrot is dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218).
>   I'm afraid your parrot is dead.

You can only use the first to extend condolences, but both might be used to inform the owner about their feline.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear answer! Just one question: in sentence 3, if I choose "I'm sorry" is the comma compulsory or optional after "sorry"? Actually, as there is no comma, I would have chosen "afraid". Is "sorry" correct without any comma in this sentence?

Comment: The comma is optional for either "I'm sorry" or "I'm afraid".

Comment: @Peter Are you certain there is no difference in meaning between "I'm sorry, his line is busy." and "I'm sorry his line is busy."? I would say Jessica is correct in saying that "afraid" is the only correct option (with the assumed context in mind) in the comma-less version, and "sorry" would be correct only if it was followed by a comma. I would use "I'm sorry his line is busy." as an apology to someone complaining that "his" line is busy, as in this conversation: A: *...but his line is engaged and I can't reach him!* B: *I'm sorry his line is busy, but I can't do anything about it.*

Comment: Not just BrE.  "I'm afraid he's not in the office at the moment" would not be unusual in AmE.

Comment: @user2684291  the comma is, I think, not relevant to the meaning.  Either way it could be an actual apology or a simple excuse.  The only way to know is from context.

Comment: @user2684291 I think there's a cultural context involved. "I'm afraid" is more used in the UK, in the US they would simply say "He's on another call, would you like to leave a message?".

Comment: @Peter In effect, I asked, and I'll restate it: Can't the comma-less sentence ("I'm sorry his line is busy.") expand into the following (or be interpreted as): "I'm sorry that his line is busy."?

Comment: I don't think so since the speaker would have no control over the line being busy, why would they apologize? Perhaps it could expand into "I'm sorry for you that his line is busy." in the same way as "I'm sorry your cat died."  The comma is optional.

Answer (score -1):

*I'm afraid* can also mean *Sorry*, when a request will probably not be fullfilled or attended. However, in order to perfom this function, a *personal pronoun* must come after *afraid*, also you can see that when talking about fearing something, it is usually proceeded by: *ing*. Pay attention to these examples:

> *I'm afraid of asking the teacher* = I don't want to ask the teacher, I'm ashamed.
>
> *I'm afraid '**HE**' has just left* = Sorry, he has just left.
>
> *I'm afraid of diving into this sea* = This sea may be deep, and I'm afraid of heigh.
>
> *I'm afraid '**Mr.Thompson**' is busy in a meeting right now*. = Sorry, but Mr.Thompson is having a meeting now, therefore he can't talk to
>   you.

Therefore:

I’m ***sorry*** / ***afraid*** I can’t speak Spanish very well.

I’m ***sorry***, can you say that again please?

I’m **sorry** / ***afraid*** his line is busy.

I’m ***sorry*** / ***afraid*** but he’s in a meeting at the moment.